# List of tuples generated through list comprehension

Tags: haskell

The function returns a list of tuples which is generated through list comprehension:

```
getUserRatings :: String -> [Film] -> [(String,Int)]
getUserRatings search database = [(title,rate) | (Film title _ _ ratings) <- database, (user,rate) <- ratings, search == user]
```

Film is defined as:

```
type Rating = (String, Int)
data Film = Film {  title,director :: String,
                    year :: Int,
                    ratings :: [Rating] } deriving (Read,Show)
```

such that a database is:

```
testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase = [(Film "Blade Runner" "Ridley Scott" 1982 [("Amy",5),("Bill",8),("Ian",7),("Kevin",9),("Emma",4),("Sam",7),("Megan",4)])]
```

The function `getUserRatings` takes in a the users name and the database, searches the ratings in the database, then compiles the the tuple so that its in the format of:

> film name (String), user rating (Int)

How might I write this more efficiently using higher order functions? I've attempted a few times but to no success using filters and maps; I don't know whether to post those attempts here or not. So I won't until advised otherwise.

Comment: "How might I write this more efficiently using higher order functions?" More __efficiently__ or more __readable__? Your current version isn't that much different from `concatMap` + `filter` + `map`.

Comment: @Zeta readable is probably better in my case. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using high-order functions is not much readable:

```
userRatings search = concatMap (\film ->
  map ((title film,) . snd)
    $ filter ((==search) . fst) $ ratings film)
```

You need `{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}` to be able to write `(title film,)`.

Another useful extension is `NamedFieldPuns`.

```
getUserRatings search database
  = [ (title,rate)
    | Film{title, ratings} <- database
    , (user,rate) <- ratings
    , search == user
    ]
```

Writing `Film{title, ratings}` instead of `Film title _ _ ratings` is not only a bit shorter, it also allows you to change/reorder fields in `Film` without updating `getUserRatings`.

Btw, in my opinion, splitting `getUserRatings` in several lines adds more readability than rewriting it somehow.